# How do I update parent div of component in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I was just wondering if this is even possible, lets assume I have this code here:

```
<div v-for="tile in container" v-bind:class="proper-class">
    <tile :tile='tile' @update="update-class"></tile>
</div>
```

I want to change the css class of the parent div when a variable inside of the component changes.

I know we should use `$emit` but we have a `v-for` in here, so we're creating multiple components, the `$emit callback` will update `proper-class` BUT this will update the css class of ALL the parents and not just the parent of the component that issued the `update` event.

What could be a solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if each tile in container is an object, you can add a property like `updated: true/false` and use it to bind the css class : `:class="{'proper-class': tile.updated}"`

Comment: But `tile` is passed as a prop, if I update it inside of the component it will not get updated inside of the vue instance because all props form a one-way-down binding, so that wouldn't work. Unless you mean something else.

Comment: Oh unless you mean that I should manually update `tile` object using the `$emit` callback, yes that would work, thank you. Is there any "better" way to do this though?

Comment: Yes it's that, you use the `$emit` to update the `tile` status in the parent. The `$emit` event is the Vue way to pass data from a child component to a parent.

Comment: Alright, merci beacoup.

Comment: Also, I found out that instead of using `$emit` I could just use sync like so `<tile :tile.sync='tile' @update="update-class"></tile>`, thought I'd share it: [.sync Modifier](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sync` modifier to create a two way binding between the parent and child. It's nothing more than syntactic sugar for the child component emitting an event back to the parent with the desired payload.

```
this.$emit('update:propName', payload)
```

[Vue sync modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)

Comment: Got it in the comments above, thanks though. Anyways, I think there's a weird bug or something because in the component I updated this.tile.properclass and it automatically updated in the parent even though I'm not using `$emit` or the `sync modifier`. What do you think?

Comment: I think you're already essentially doing what sync does by using `v-bind` and `@update` in the example. Like the docs mention, `sync` is emitting the update event under the hood so it's the same either way you look at it.

Comment: I'm not, this is what I have now: `<div v-for="tile in container" v-bind:class="tile.proper-class"><tile :tile='tile' :filters='filters'></tile></div>`. Inside the component I'm doing `this.tile.proper-class="new value"`. It's also getting updated in the parent, that's very weird...

Comment: That is strange. Do you have the Vue dev tools extension installed? If so, can you see if an event is getting emitted and possibly picked up? What you have posted there shouldn't reflect any sort of two way binding.

Comment: Ikr, I'll look into it and get back to you, just in case there's a bug maybe.

Comment: There's no event being emitted, this is very strange right now, gonna double check all my code just in case I made a mistake somewhere, but even if I did Vue dev tools is supposed to catch it, it isn't catching anything.

Comment: I'm assuming since this the prop is an object, it's getting passed by reference, so updating it will update the parent. The Vue js documentary mentions this here [Component Props](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html). We're suppose to get a warning when doing so but we're not, I guess it's not a bug after all. What they mean with "One-Way Data Flow" is that even variables passed by value will be updated in all child components if the parent does it, though this doesn't prevent anything else... Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marioada/gqofggzd/) to reproduce this.

Comment: Ok I see whats going on now, since the `visible` property is not explicitly declared on the tile object, Vue does not track it's changes, hence no error in the console when assigning directly in the watcher. If you do something like `this.tile = null` instead, you will see the console error about mutating properties. If you need reactivity on a property that gets added after the component is created, use `Vue.set()` instead of directly assigning.

Comment: Alright, I don't think `reactivity` has anything to do with it since `visible` is already there but I'll check it out anyways, thanks.

Comment: Yeah I completely overlooked that where it was setup in the container variable. Well, I thought I had a good idea there.